# How can I put a callback into an Intent?

Tags: android, service

I want to a start a Service with an Intent that contains a callback. How can I do that? I want to use startService(...), not the binding mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use a custom broadcast which will be sent by the service. You can register for that broadcast in your activity and catch that. That would be the standard solution for a *service callback*. You can't put complex data (like references) in your intent, simple and primitive data only...

[Custom Intents and Broadcasting with Receivers](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)

**Update** based on comment

How to interpret [this presentation](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf) then (slide 11, number in bottom left corner)?

In this case they're using a service helper. I think they start the server with `startService` to symbolize that the service should stay awake. A `bindService` would stop the service when the binding activity is destroyed. The service helper will call `bindService` anyway because it says `10. Binder callback`. So in the end the helper seems to be a bind wrapper for the requesting activity so the activities have not to deal with the whole service communication.

That's the way I would interpret it...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am doing now. But I was wondering what is the Binder callback in this presentation, slide 11 - http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf. Notice that the Service is started with startService().

Comment: Sorry, it's the first slide that has number 11 in the bottom left corner. It's a diagram titled Option A: Use a Service API.